# What is the best way to get combinations of two lists in Python -

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cartesian-product

Here is what I want to do.

I have two Pandas DataFrames

List of items and Qty to buy

```
ITEM, QTY    
A,1
B,2
C,3
```

Locations at which each ITEM is available. One item can be available at multiple locations.

```
ITEM, LOCATION
A, LOC1
B, LOC2
B, LOC3
C, LOC4
C, LOC5
```

I need to find out all the possible combinations the ITEMS can be purchased

**Combination 1**

```
A, LOC1
B, LOC2
C, LOC4
```

**Combination 2**

```
A, LOC1
B, LOC2
C, LOC5
```

**Combination 3**

```
A, LOC1
B, LOC3
C, LOC4
```

**Combination 4**

```
A, LOC1
B, LOC3
C, LOC5
```

Comment: Use `itertools`; you need the `product` of the location sets.

Comment: How does the quantity available affect the solution you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product`. For a variable number of variables, you can use a dictionary.

```
from itertools import product

d = df2.groupby('ITEM')['LOCATION'].apply(list).to_dict()

dfs = {i: pd.DataFrame({'LOCATION': j}).assign(ITEM=d.keys())
          for i, j in enumerate(product(*d.values()), 1)}

print(dfs)

{1:   LOCATION ITEM
    0     LOC1    A
    1     LOC2    B
    2     LOC4    C,
 2:   LOCATION ITEM
    0     LOC1    A
    1     LOC2    B
    2     LOC5    C,
 3:   LOCATION ITEM
    0     LOC1    A
    1     LOC3    B
    2     LOC4    C,
 4:   LOCATION ITEM
    0     LOC1    A
    1     LOC3    B
    2     LOC5    C}
```